# How to add rules in Linux kernel Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel, system-calls

I want to add systemcall to Linux kernel **3.6.x**. I have two files `myheader.h` and `mycode.c`.

As I have seen on some articles, I did the following:

1. Create a folder from root directory `/linux/myfolder`.
2. Create Makefile in `myfolder` with the rule:

   `obj-y := mycode.o`

   and I put `mycode.c` file in this folder.
3. I modify the main Makefile form the root directory.

   `core-y := usr/  myfolder/`

Where should I put `myheader.h` and what rules should I have to add to the makefiles ?

I tried putting it inside `/linux/include` but it fails to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have header file locally(within same directory as source file), and include it with simple `#include "myheader.h"`.